# Cobol - How do I determine the length and position of the content in a PIC N field?

Tags: cobol

I've found I tend to attack problems in chunks that are too big, so here's my
attempt at starting with something smaller and more specific.

I'm working exclusively with PIC N fields, which are National fields. I need to determine the length and position of the content in that field for a program I'm working on.

The specific field I'm talking about is defined as follows:

`05 Bank-CODE PIC N(10).`

There could be leading spaces, there could be trailing spaces. I will need to test it for embedded spaces too, at some point.

Basically the goal is to be able to work with the content of this field without the spaces.

Now, I know how to determine the length of the field itself:

`05  BANK-CODE                   PIC  N(10).
05  BK-LENGTH                   PIC S9(04) COMP.
MOVE LENGTH OF BANK-CODE TO BK-LENGTH
COMPUTE BK-LENGTH = FUNCTION LENGTH (BANK-CODE)`

I just don't know how to determine the length and position of the content in BANK-CODE.

Comment: Go on, tell us which compiler and Operating System you are using :-)

Comment: Why is all your data National? Do you actually have the possibility of characters which are neither alphabetic nor numeric?

Comment: Good questions. I don't know why we're using National, exactly. My first interpretation was that as long as my input and output was in National, I could put in the working storage what I wanted. Then I asked my senior developer colleague and he said I have to use National for pretty much everything, including the WS section.

Comment: As for my compiler, I have absolutely no clue. I asked around and everyone is like "It's not the newest, but pretty new." I'm going to ask my project manager tomorrow about the specifics. If anyone knows, it's gonna be him. I'm on a Windows 7 32 bit laptop, but I think we're using z/OS for COBOL.

Comment: Oh stupid, I misinterpreted your question. Well, the assignment literally says: "For all fields: embedded spaces not allowed; only 0-9 and A-Z." and later it is mentioned that if the input doesn't fit these standards, I need to give an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is "trim", or the information which would allow you to trim leading and trailing spaces from a field.

COBOL doesn't have one. Unless, as mentioned previously, you are using a compiler like GnuCOBOL, which does. But I'd guess you are using IBM's Enterprise COBOL. If you are, the name and particular version will be shown at the top of each page on your compiler output listing.

Just because COBOL doesn't have a trim, does not stop you. It just means you need code.

Here's some from "out there" (search-engine for S8833TR.pdf, the link is long, a long story) and find the section on *Coding tips from customer situations*:

```
MOVE ' This is string 1 ' TO TEXT1
COMPUTE POS1 POS2 = 0
INSPECT TEXT1
   TALLYING POS1
   FOR LEADING SPACES
INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE(TEXT1)
   TALLYING POS2
   FOR LEADING SPACES
MOVE TEXT1(POS1:LENGTH OF TEXT1 - POS2 - POS1)
 TO TEXT2
```

And

```
MOVE ' This is string 1 ' TO TEXT1
PERFORM VARYING POS1 FROM 1 BY 1
  UNTIL TEXT1(POS1:1) NOT = SPACE
END-PERFORM
PERFORM VARYING POS2 FROM LENGTH OF TEXT1
   BY -1 UNTIL TEXT1(POS2:1) NOT = SPACE
END-PERFORM
COMPUTE LEN = POS2 - POS1 + 1
MOVE TEXT1(POS1 : LEN) TO TEXT2 (1 : LEN)
```

You will see in the document that, as you were told, there is some performance implication with `FUNCTION REVERSE` (the first block of code is 31% slower than the second), but be careful in avoiding it. It is easier to code and understand, if slower to run. If your subprogram is going to be used *a lot*, then taking performance into account is worthwhile.

The code is provided by IBM's Tom Ross.

Tom's code uses "reference modification". This is a way that a sub-field of a field can be defined, at compile time (if start position and length are known) or on-the-fly at run-time if either or both of start position and length are variable. Reference-modification is a very fast way of accessing data. It is also a very lazy and sloppy way of accessing data which obfuscates code (there may be a little bit of opinion showing there, which just ever-so-slightly may not be held by others).

Instead of reference-modification, the next pieces of code use something like this:

```
       01  the-text                        PIC X(30).
       01  FILLER 
           REDEFINES the-text.
           05  FILLER 
               OCCURS 30 TIMES.
               10  the-byte-of-text        PIC X.
```

the-byte-of-text can then be referenced by subscripting, rather than the group-item (the text) being referenced.

The POS1 will likely be be defined the same for the reference-modification and the subscripting. Or it can be. I'd go for PIC 99 BINARY (BINARY/COMP/COMP-4 are identical in Enterprise COBOL) but your colleagues may well insist on PIC S9(4) COMP (old habits die hard).

Now, if you want it even faster:

```
       PERFORM 
         VARYING                    POS1 
           FROM                     1 
           BY                       1 
         UNTIL                      ( NOT TEXT1-BYTE-IS-SPACE 
                                       ( POS1 ) )
       END-PERFORM 
       MOVE TEXT1 ( POS1 : )        TO TEXT2
```

There's actually a piece missing from Tom's code, the initialisation of TEXT2.

This code (mine) deals with that by not using the "length" in the reference-modification. Why not? COBOL fields are fixed-length (except the variable-length ones) so you can't "get rid of" the trailing spaces. For that example, then, don't bother to find the trailing spaces, and use the final MOVE to ensure that no data is left in TEXT2 from the previous execution of the code (there would be in Tom's example).

Note that I used REDEFINES and a data-names as a subcripts (POS1) and an 88-level condition-name. As well as faster, you can make code clearer. Within limits, you can do both at the same time.

For your task you *do* want to know the length of the trailing spaces:

One problem with examples is that often they aren't complete, like the missing initialisation. Another thing that isn't complete is that all the code assumes there is at least one non-blank present (since a literal is used as the source). That's often unrealistic, and definitely no use in your case.

People will often deal with the more general case by including "make sure I haven't run off the end" in their termination condition for the PERFORM. However, multiple conditions are more difficult to understand, and run more slowly.

```
       IF field-in-use-is-blank
           PERFORM                  no-field-to-deal-with
       ELSE
           PERFORM                  field-to-deal-with
       END-IF
```

So immediately make two different cases. Within field-to-deal-with you can know that there is at least one non-blank character. In no-field-to-deal-with you know that the entire field is blank.

field-in-use-is-blank is an 88-level condition-name on your field.

```
   01  your-field                          PIC X(40).
       88  field-in-use-is-blank           VALUE SPACE.
```

Note that the names I've used are for explication only. I always suggest meaningful names for your actual purpose.

```
       PERFORM 
         VARYING                    POS2 
           FROM                     LENGTH OF TEXT1 
           BY -1 
         UNTIL                      ( TEXT1-SPACE-CHECK 
                                       ( POS2 )
                                     NOT EQUAL TO SPACE )
       END-PERFORM 
       COMPUTE LEN                  = ( POS2 
                                      - POS1 ) 
                                      + 1
```

Going backwards from the end of the field you can't use an 88-level.

Now you have LEN. I would use different names for everything, but that's me.

Here are the relevant data-definitions:

```
   01  FILLER REDEFINES TEXT1. 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 50 TIMES. 
           10  TEXT1-SPACE-CHECK           PIC X. 
               88  TEXT1-BYTE-IS-SPACE     VALUE SPACE.

   01  LEN                          COMP   PIC S9(4).
   01  POS1                         COMP   PIC S9(4).
   01  POS2                         COMP   PIC S9(4).
```

TEXT1 was just a 50-byte PIC X field. There are many ways to skin an egg. The code above shows how POS1 is used in reference-modification, and also for subscripting. The sizes and types of LEN, POS1 and POS2 were best guesses. They could all be BINARY (let's me modern, and since it is just a typing thing...) PIC 99. There are cases where that definition will be more efficient over the original, otherwise the same. Don't expect to convince any of your Seniors of that.

COBOL is in the main very much a "team" thing. Do things the way they are done at your site. If the local "standards" are poor or outdated, you can always try to change them, but coding how others code (for techniques) means easier team understanding. Obviously using meaningful names is a benefit in itself, which is unconnected to techniques.

The above is for PIC X (or PIC A, but you're not likely to see those) fields. What is different for PIC N? Just the `FUNCTION LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH OF`.

However, there is a potential performance issue with PIC N. Behind the scenes, if necessary, the compiler will convert the National to Alphanumeric, and back again. For performance, and with only numbers and the a plain latinic alphabet, I'd only convert everything to PIC N at the last moment. And that can be as little as a simple `MOVE`, and the compiler generates the code for you.

Forgot to add that you were already shown a link to a "trimmer" as well: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69220/21548

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I know I might be nagging, but I don't get what your POS1 and TEXT1-SPACE-CHECK contain. Can you please explain that to me? I'm a complete newbie to coding and Cobol and though I've had a course, I'm still struggling with quite a few things, as you've undoubtedly noticed by now.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time again Bill :-) As for the elaboration, it has made things a bit clearer, but I still struggle a bit with that last bit of code you wrote. I just don't see where the value of POS1 gets declared or filled so it can be useful when it's subtracted from POS2. Same goes for TEXT1-SPACE-CHECK. I'm ashamed to admit it but I just don't understand how it works yet. I imagine that can be frustrating for a veteran like you, so if you want to throw the rtfm phrase at me, I understand

Comment: Hi Bill, sorry to bother you, but is it still possible for you to explain the TEXT1-SPACE-CHECK and POS1 in the last bit of code you posted in this answer. It looks really useful so I'd really like to understand it, if you have time.

Comment: I've put the definitions in. If you want to understand more, you'd best ask a new question, as otherwise we'd go off the current topic and confuse the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps me understand how it works

Comment: I know this answer is quite old, but as it still shows up in the search results... most COBOL implementation actually have `FUNCTION TRIM`, maybe it would be good to edit the well written answer.
One thing that possibly is "not 100% correct" is the performance of `PIC N` - most (all?) compilers use UTF16 for this, so each character position uses two bytes - no need for any conversion for most statements, at least as long as one statement only uses either all `NATIONAL` or `DISPLAY`.